# hyper client coldfusion facing some errors

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am using hyper library for coldfusion for cfhttp

here is the code I am using

Trying to use the API for this but it is coming as an error

```
<cfset Application.hyper = new models.HyperRequest()>

<CFSCRIPT>
  Application.hyper.setMethod("POST")
    .setUrl('https://demo2.2c2p.com/2C2PFrontEnd/RedirectV3/payment')
    .setBody({
        version: '8.5',
        merchant_id: 'JT04',
        currency: '702',
        result_url_1: 'http://localhost:8888/hyper/result.cfm',
        hash_value: hash_value,
        payment_description: 'Test',
        order_id : '#Timeformat(now())#',
        amount : '000000002500'
    }).send();
</CFSCRIPT>
```

ERROR I AM GETTING IS

```
"Host name may not be empty"
```

Comment: Looks like nobody did some work on hyper, but only shared the link do with this, i raised the issue with Author, but he does not have time to do this, in these situations when persons owns a code and they don't guide or fix any issues , the person waiting on other side will defintaely switch to other case like using cfhttp directly rathaer than this, but if something is build, please do support it actively, no just throw away to the user to use it by brainstorming it because every user codes with different terminology

Comment: and next person does not know what the other person has written and why did it this way. So if you can't suppose, please do not market the code in stackoverflow or in cfml slack channel, i saw one question here mentioning to user `hyper`, but if someone stucks with any issue, it is either the developer who can help solve it or any other who has some familarity how it was used. i tried 2 different techniques and none of them work, even one specified by the developer itself